# FFT normalization

Tags: signal-processing, fft, normalization

I know this question has been asked ad nauseam but somehow I can't make it work properly. I created a single, sine wave of 440 Hz having  a unit amplitude. Now, after the FFT, the bin at 440 Hz has a distinct peak but the value just isn't right. I'd expect to see 0 dB since I'm dealing with a unit amplitude sine wave. Instead, the power calculated is well above 0 dB. The formula I'm using is simply

```
for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) 
{  
    mag = sqrt((Real[i]*Real[i] + Img[i]*Img[i])/(N*0.54)); //0.54 correction for a Hamming Window

    Mag[i] = 10 * log(mag) ;      
}
```

I should probably point out that the total energy in the time domain is equal to the energy in the frequency domain (Parseval's theorem), so I know that my FFT routine is fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the correct way to calculate dB is  20*log10, if you are using a Hamming Window before perform the FFT can be a problem get right dB scale

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this again for work.  It seems that a lot of software routines / books are a bit sloppy on the normalization of the FFT.
The best summary I have is:  Energy needs to be conserved - which is Parseval's theorem.  Also when coding this in Python, you can easily loose an element and not know it.  Note that numpy.arrays indexing is not inclusive of the last element.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a[1:-1] = [2,3,4,5]
a[-1] = 6
```

Here's my code to normalize the FFT properly:

```py
# FFT normalization to conserve power
    
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal
    
    
sample_rate = 500.0e6
time_step = 1/sample_rate
    
carrier_freq = 100.0e6
    
    
# number of digital samples to simulate
num_samples = 2**18 # 262144
t_stop = num_samples*time_step
t = np.arange(0, t_stop, time_step)
    
# let the signal be a voltage waveform,
# so there is no zero padding
carrier_I = np.sin(2*np.pi*carrier_freq*t)
    
#######################################################
# FFT using Welch method
# windows = np.ones(nfft) - no windowing
# if windows = 'hamming', etc.. this function will
# normalize to an equivalent noise bandwidth (ENBW)
#######################################################
nfft = num_samples  # fft size same as signal size 
f,Pxx_den = scipy.signal.welch(carrier_I, fs = 1/time_step,\
                        window = np.ones(nfft),\
                        nperseg = nfft,\
                        scaling='density')
    
#######################################################
# FFT comparison    
#######################################################
    
integration_time = nfft*time_step
power_time_domain = sum((np.abs(carrier_I)**2)*time_step)/integration_time
print 'power time domain = %f' % power_time_domain
    
# Take FFT.  Note that the factor of 1/nfft is sometimes omitted in some 
# references and software packages.
# By proving Parseval's theorem (conservation of energy) we can find out the 
# proper normalization.
signal = carrier_I 
xdft = scipy.fftpack.fft(signal, nfft)/nfft 
# fft coefficients need to be scaled by fft size
# equivalent to scaling over frequency bins
# total power in frequency domain should equal total power in time domain
power_freq_domain = sum(np.abs(xdft)**2)
print 'power frequency domain = %f' % power_freq_domain
# Energy is conserved
    
    
# FFT symmetry
plt.figure(0)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(np.abs(xdft)) # symmetric in amplitude
plt.title('magnitude')
plt.subplot(2,1,2) 
plt.plot(np.angle(xdft)) # pi phase shift out of phase
plt.title('phase')
plt.show()
    
xdft_short = xdft[0:nfft/2+1] # take only positive frequency terms, other half identical
# xdft[0] is the dc term
# xdft[nfft/2] is the Nyquist term, note that Python 2.X indexing does NOT 
# include the last element, therefore we need to use 0:nfft/2+1 to have an array
# that is from 0 to nfft/2
# xdft[nfft/2-x] = conjugate(xdft[nfft/2+x])
Pxx = (np.abs(xdft_short))**2 # power ~ voltage squared, power in each bin.
Pxx_density = Pxx / (sample_rate/nfft)  # power is energy over -fs/2 to fs/2, with nfft bins
Pxx_density[1:-1] = 2*Pxx_density[1:-1] # conserve power since we threw away 1/2 the spectrum
# note that DC (0 frequency) and Nyquist term only appear once, we don't double those.
# Note that Python 2.X array indexing is not inclusive of the last element.
    
    
    
Pxx_density_dB = 10*np.log10(Pxx_density)
freq = np.linspace(0,sample_rate/2,nfft/2+1) 
# frequency range of the fft spans from DC (0 Hz) to 
# Nyquist (Fs/2).
# the resolution of the FFT is 1/t_stop
# dft of size nfft will give nfft points at frequencies
# (1/stop) to (nfft/2)*(1/t_stop)
    
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(freq,Pxx_density_dB,'^')
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(f, 10.0*np.log10(Pxx_den))
plt.xlabel('Freq (Hz)'),plt.ylabel('dBm/Hz'),#plt.show()
plt.ylim([-200, 0])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Many common (but not all) FFT libraries scale the FFT result of a unit amplitude sinusoid by the length of the FFT.  This maintains Parsevals equality since a longer sinusoid represents more total energy than a shorter one of the same amplitude.

If you don't want to scale by the FFT length when using one of these libraries, then divide by the length before computing the magnitude in dB.

Comment: Thanks,hotpaw2. I'm already doing that. Anyway, I've also noticed that  popular audio editors are also inconsistent (when one editor is compared to another), so it seems that FFT normalization/scaling is somewhat arbitrary (or at least not well standardized).

Answer (score 0):

Normalization can be done in many different ways - depending on window, number of samples, etc.

Common trick: take FFT of known signal and normalize by the value of the peak. Say in the above example your peak is `123` - if you want it to be `1`, then divide it ( and all results obtained with this algorithm) by 123.

Comment: My input data all fall in the range -1 to 1. In the Scientist and engineer's guide to digita signal pocessing, the author explains in detail the steps needed to perform FFT normalization. Unfortunately, this part of the book is kind of vague (to me anyway). If you're interested you can take a look (http://www.dspguide.com/ch10.htm). And, thanks for your help

Comment: My point is that "scaling" is just a multiplication - and since you often have all kinds of calibrations and conversions in signal processing (did `1000` input mean volts, mV, W/m^2 ?....) there is little point in an FFT library implementing any kind of scaling - so they often don't and leave it up to you. The method I described works well - although for speed you compute `1.0/123.0` just once, and multiply (division is much slower than multiplication...)